# How do I run code in the UI thread in an Android JUnit test without an Activity?

Tags: android, multithreading, testing, user-interface, junit

I have a database component that relies on `AsyncTask` to retrieve data. Once used in the application it will always be called from the UI thread, but how do I do that in the JUnit tests without instantiating an `Activity` (i just don't have an activity, nor should I have to create one just for testing purposes)?

`runOnUiThread()` is an activity method so it's not an option. Is there a way to simulate the UI thread either by getting one from the Android test library or by implementing a MockUiThread?

Comment: What's the base class of your test ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Android.OS.Handler should be able to update the ui.

To use a handler you have to subclass it and overide handleMessage() to process messages

**Update:**

I am using monodroid, so I dont know if this is completely translatable, But,

You may be able to use

```
new Handler(context.getMainLooper()).post(runnable);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works in regular Android too. :) In another thread I read that all I really have to do is instantiate one AsyncTask in the UI thread before I create any others and the following ones will automatically know the UI Thread, it seems to work great! Thanks.

Comment: `context` can be taken from the app as follows, if no activity is available in the test scope: `Application context = (Application)InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();`