# Android Instrumentation Testing - UI Thread Issues

Tags: java, android, multithreading, testing, junit

I am trying to write an Instrumentation Test for my Android app.

I'm running into some weird threading issues and I can't seem to find a solution.

**My Original Test:**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class WorkOrderDetailsTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<WorkOrderDetails> activityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(WorkOrderDetails.class);

    @Test
    public void loadWorkOrder_displaysCorrectly() throws Exception {
        final WorkOrderDetails activity = activityRule.getActivity();

        WorkOrder workOrder = new WorkOrder();
        activity.updateDetails(workOrder);

        //Verify customer info is displayed
        onView(withId(R.id.customer_name))
                .check(matches(withText("John Smith")));
    }
}
```

This resulted in an

> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
>
> ...
>
> com.kwtree.kwtree.workorder.WorkOrderDetails.updateDetails(WorkOrderDetails.java:155)

The only thing the `updateDetails()` method does is some `setText()` calls.

After researching a bit, it seemed like adding a `UiThreadTestRule` and `android.support.test.annotation.UiThreadTest` annotation to my test would fix the problem.

**@UiThreadTest:**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class WorkOrderDetailsTest {

    //Note: This is new
    @Rule
    public UiThreadTestRule uiThreadTestRule = new UiThreadTestRule();

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<WorkOrderDetails> activityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(WorkOrderDetails.class);

    @Test
    @UiThreadTest //Note: This is new
    public void loadWorkOrder_displaysCorrectly() throws Exception {
        final WorkOrderDetails activity = activityRule.getActivity();

        WorkOrder workOrder = new WorkOrder();
        activity.updateDetails(workOrder);

        //Verify customer info is displayed
        onView(withId(R.id.customer_name))
                .check(matches(withText("John Smith")));
    }
}
```

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method cannot be called on the main application thread (on: main)

*(Note: All of the methods in this stack trace are not my code)*

It seems to be giving me mixed results... If it needs to be run on the original thread that created the views but can't run on the main thread, what thread should it be run on?

I'd really appreciate any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Those instrumentation tests run inside their *own* app. This also means, they run in their *own thread*.

You must think of your instrumentation as something you install alongside your actual app, so your possible interactions are 'limited'.

You need to call all view methods from the UIThread / main thread of the application, so calling `activity.updateDetails(workOrder);` from your instrumentation thread is *not* the application main thread. This is why the exception is thrown.

You can just run the code you need to test on your main thread like you would do if you were calling it inside your app from a different thread by using

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        activity.updateDetails(workOrder);
    }
}
```

With this running your test should work.

The illegal state exception you are receiving seems to be because of your interaction with the rule. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/UiThreadTest.html) states

> Note that instrumentation methods may not be used when this annotation is present.

If you start / get your activity in `@Before` it should also work.

Comment: The `runOnUiThread` approach worked when combined with `getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();`. The `@Before` approach didn't work unfortunately. Thanks for the help!

Comment: ^ this is important when you have an assertion immediately after, otherwise you can get a race condition with inconsistent test results!

Comment: is there a reason why the runner can't utilise main thread to begin with, if switching to the UI thread is already possible by various means?

Answer (score 19):

You can run portion of your test on the main UI thread with the help of [`UiThreadTestRule.runOnUiThread(Runnable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/UiThreadTestRule.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)):

```
@Rule
public UiThreadTestRule uiThreadTestRule = new UiThreadTestRule();

@Test
public void loadWorkOrder_displaysCorrectly() throws Exception {
    final WorkOrderDetails activity = activityRule.getActivity();

    uiThreadTestRule.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            WorkOrder workOrder = new WorkOrder();
            activity.updateDetails(workOrder);
        }
    });

    //Verify customer info is displayed
    onView(withId(R.id.customer_name))
            .check(matches(withText("John Smith")));
}
```

In most cases it is simpler to annotate the test method with `UiThreadTest`, however, it may incur other errors such as `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method cannot be called on the main application thread (on: main)`.

FYR, here is a quote from [`UiThreadTest`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/annotation/UiThreadTest.html)'s Javadoc:

> Note, due to current JUnit limitation, methods annotated with `Before` and `After` will also be executed on the UI Thread. **Consider using runOnUiThread(Runnable) if this is an issue.**

Please note `UiThreadTest` (package `android.support.test.annotation`) mentioned above is different from ([`UiThreadTest`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/UiThreadTest.html) (package `android.test`)).

Comment: Strangely, this did not solve my issue

Answer (score 16):

The accepted answer is now **deprecated**

The easiest way to achieve this is simply using `UiThreadTest`

```
import android.support.test.annotation.UiThreadTest;

        @Test
        @UiThreadTest
        public void myTest() {
            // Set up conditions for test

            // Call the tested method
            activity.doSomethingWithAView()

            // Verify that the results are correct
        }
```

Comment: If future visitors stumble upon `Android.Test.UIThreadTest is deprecated as of API 24: Android 7.0 (Nougat)`, note that this is not the same annotation. This answer is using the support annotation. That cannot be resolved for me though

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5798569/2550406) worked for me on Nougat

Comment: In `myTest` where did `activity` come from? That's what I'm stuck on.

Answer (score 11):

With the androidx test runner a new class was added `UiThreadStatement` that gives a `runOnUiThread` method for this.

```
        UiThreadStatement.runOnUiThread {
           // call activity here 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer describes what is going on perfectly.

As an addition, in case someone is curious why Espresso's methods that touch the UI e.g. `perform(ViewActions ...)` don't need to do the same, it is simply because they end up doing it later for us.

If you follow `perform(ViewActions ...)` you will find it ends up doing the following (in `android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction`):

```
private void runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(Runnable action) {
    ...
    mainThreadExecutor.execute(uiTask);
    ...
}
```

That `mainThreadExecutor` is itself annotated with `@MainThread`.

In other words, Espresso also needs to play by the same rules described by David on the accepted answer.