# Not able to perform click action on image view (Espresso)

Tags: android-espresso

I am working on automation testing of the Android app using Espresso. I am not able to perform click action on some image views on recycler view. I have tried to perform click by retrieving the required image view by going through its hierarchy but I am getting 'android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException' exception while performing click action which is working fine on other recycler views. I also tried to perform click by getting coordinates of the image view.
I have tried some solutions through the following links:

[Android Instrumentation Testing - UI Thread Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35183981/android-instrumentation-testing-ui-thread-issues)
[Click by bounds / coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177590/click-by-bounds-coordinates)

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. For this problem, I tried following steps to solve:
1. I retrieved the image view through its hierarchical view.
2. Created custom ViewAction method in which we are taking image view as an argument instead of id as shown in example 1 on the link given below.
3. Retrieved the root view by their id and passed the view action in its ViewAction part of espresso.
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.support.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction